# Container div not working (trying to stop my page from resizing)

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding and trying to put together a basic website that I might use as a portfolio if I can get it to work and look good.

Unfortunately, what I have so far looks awful unless it is full-sized. I want to prevent it from being resized as a temporary fix, but min-height and min-width aren't working. None of the solutions to stopping resizing I've found so far have worked.

I assume it's because my code is terrible, but can anyone help me prevent my page from resizing?

```css
body {
  background-color: #91bfe6;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif; 
}

.container {
  min-width: 1920; 
  min-height: 1080;  
}

.p01 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua",Palatino,serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 5%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.p02 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 5%;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  word-spacing: 30px;   

}

.p03 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua",Palatino,serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 4px;
  top: 62px;
}

.p04 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 5%;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  word-spacing: 30px; 
  position: relative;
  top: 15px; 
  z-index: 1;
}

#bottomtext {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 24px;

}


#footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 4px;
  top: 62px;

}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 24px;
  top: 11px;

}

#links {
  position: fixed;
  right: 112px;
  top: 10px;


}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 5%;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#rectangle {

  background: #834f47;
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;
  height: calc(100vh - 86px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#img5 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;
  margin-right: 40px;

}

#img6 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;

}

#img7 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;

}



#img8 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 86px;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#storememo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#contact {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 210%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1><a href="Index.html">MY NAME</a></h1>
    <p class="p01">
      <a href="illustration.html">illustration</a> - <a href="3D.html">3D </a>- <a href="animation.html">animation </a>- <a href="graphicdesign.html">graphic design</a>
    </p>
  </div>   

  <div id="links">
    <p class="p02">
      <a href="about.html">ABOUT </a> | <a href="contact.html"> CONTACT </a> | <a href="storelink.html"> STORE </a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="bottomtext">
    <p class="p04">ILLUSTRATION</p></div>

  <div id="rectangle"></div>

  <div id="img5">
    <a href="placeholder.html">
      <img src="placeholder.png" alt="thumbnail" style="width:210px;height:480px;"/>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="img6">
    <a href="placeholder.html">
      <img src="placeholder.png" alt="thumbnail" style="width:210px;height:480px;"/>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="img7">
    <a href="placeholder.html"><img src="placeholder.png" alt="thumbnail" style="width:210px;height:480px;"/>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="img8">
    <a href="placeholder.html">
      <img src="placeholder.png" alt="thumbnail" style="width:210px;height:480px;"/>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="img9">
    <a href="placeholder.html">
      <img src="placeholder.png" alt="thumbnail" style="width:210px;height:480px;"/>
    </a></div>


  <div id="footer"> 
    <footer>
      <p class="p03">(c) MY NAME </p> 
    </footer> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "prevent your page from resizing", are you reffering to preventing the user from resizing your page in their browser? Because that is impossible. Or are you saying simply cut off elements (don't scale) based on how much of the window is showing? Or are you saying scale everything down based on the window size?

Comment: Also, please looking at posting a [MCVE] for help faster.

Comment: I mean cut off elements (don't scale) so there's a scroll bar to see the rest of the page instead of elements moving around. Thanks for the link, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: what you meant by <p04> ?

Comment: Oh ok got you, thats achievable.

Comment: So should I put fixed values in pixels for the location and size of everything? That's a lot of work... I thought I could prevent it from scaling using my container div but the container is doing nothing.

Comment: @Pascal see my answer, you can use the `min-width` and `min-height` properties on your div.

Comment: <p04> is where I put my bottom text? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Pascal <p04> is not an html element.

Comment: Oh oops I'll delete that, didn't see that there.

Comment: You are using position fixed inside the container. Position fixed is fixed to the window and doesn't care what's is container is doing. Use position absolute inside a container. Make sure your container has position relative

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search of "prevent page from resizing" would lead you to this as the first result: [Stop the browser from pushing everything around when I resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641436/stop-the-browser-from-pushing-everything-around-when-i-resize)

You can use the CSS `min-width` and `min-height` attribute to specify the minimum width/height the page can be displayed with. If this is not met, it will create a scrollbar.

Example:

```
body {
    min-width: 1920px; 
    min-height: 1080px; 
}
```

If the browser window is not 1920 * 1080, it will display what it can and create scrollbars for the rest.

Also, 
`<p04>` and `<p03>` are not html elements. Your closing tags for the `<p>` elements you have craeted are just `</p>` These are the class names that you can give to a p element using the `class=''` attribute so you can group select alike items in css.

Comment: Thanks but I did actually find that result with Google an hour ago and tried putting that in my CSS and it does nothing. When I resize the window everything still moves around and messes it up.

Comment: Which element did you add that too @Pascal ?

Comment: I put it under body?

Comment: @Pascal create a div under body that wraps all of the code, then add it to that div's css.

Comment: I moved container so it would be under body then replaced container's CSS but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Pascal update the code in the question to reflect these changes.

Comment: @Pascal my bad, In my example I did not include the unit, `px`. Try updating that css for `container` to show px after each number. no space, see my updated example.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work. Is it because my img divs are fixed?

Comment: @Pascal I don't know. But the real problem here is that the HTML has many errors, you still have closing tags like `</p01>`. Those aren't real HTML, Nothing will work until that is fixed.

Comment: I thought I fixed those?

Comment: @Pascal clearly you didn't, they are still in the code... I'd recomend you take a look at some HTML tutorials like codeacademy.com

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your output and I could say that trying to use a fixed window size out of the browser is a band-aid solution and won't actually fix your real problem which is the proportional resizing of your divs.

It's not because your coding is terrible, in fact, it's just a minor problem.
You have been using absolute units like px instead of relative units like % and em.

Absolute units are given a size but they ONLY stay that size no matter how you resize the area while relative units are given a size in relation to the viewing port which makes them resize ALONG with the viewport.

Here's a quick and dirty fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oebs8etr/1/

Try switching to fullscreen or resizing the viewport to see the difference.

HTML

```
<div class="a">RELATIVE</div>
<div class="b">FIXED</div>
```

css

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 27px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```